# Access data source inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath and pass data to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have this snippet of code below for my custom table view cell. I have 5 labels in each custom cell, which are differentiable by their tag instead of their label. (Each label has a different tag). No label id's are used. So if I were to extract the NSString from a label in the cell by the method shown below, how do I know which string is being pulled? 
I am not sure if this code can work

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NoViewController *noViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NoViewController"];
    NSString *label1 = [_nodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *label2 = [_nodes objectAtIndex:2];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Node *node = [self.nodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NodeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label;
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = node.nodeid;
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f"];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f"];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f"];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f"];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f"];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:7];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f"];
    return cell;
}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *nodeMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Node class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. The code you posted does not get an text from any labels from any cell. What is `_nodes` (besides an array)?

Comment: I think that is where my problem lies. _nodes is an array holds 6 objects, each containing 5 strings. I am confused as for how to pull the value of a string from a custom cell

Comment: How do you setup each cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? You get the data from `_nodes`, correct? Do the same thing in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. There is no need to access the cell or the labels. Simply get the strings from your nodes, just like setting up the cell.

Comment: Each label in the cells are being filled up by data from a server. That is why I need to access the cells labels after they are filled up. I need to pass these strings from the selected table cell to a detailviewcontroller after it gets clicked.

Comment: @AkhilYeleswarapu you want to pass the selected node to the detailview is that what you trying to achieve?

Comment: Update your question with your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: yes I am trying to pass the strings from the custom cell to the detailviewcontroller

Comment: @rmaddy sounds good. I just updated it

Comment: I really don't understand your question. You have no problem accessing the proper node data to populate a cell based on the cell's indexPath. You should access the node data exactly the same way in your `didSelectRow` method based on the indexPath. Get the `Node` object and go from there.

Comment: @rmaddy could you suggest some code for that process, I am a beginner at ios development.

Comment: @AkhilYeleswarapu Look at the answer by "meda". That answer get's the proper node, just you already do in your `cellForRow...` method.

Comment: thanks for the help rmaddy and meda!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to perform a segue, then assign the selected node in `prepareForSegue` :

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:self];
}
```

**prepareForSegue**

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NoViewController *noViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NoViewController"];
        noViewController.selectedNode = [_nodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    }
}
```

**DetailViewController.h**

```
#import "Node.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) Node *selectedNode;//or whatever type
@end
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

  mylabel1.text = _selectedNode.lastdelivered1;
  mylabel2.text = _selectedNode.lastdelivered2;
  //and so forth
}
```

Comment: BY doing this, how can I access the labels in each cell?

Comment: @AkhilYeleswarapu you dont access the label you access the datasource, thats the whole point of MVC, place this line in the prepareForSegue
`Node *node = [self.nodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` and access it

Comment: okay I am getting an error on noViewController.selectedNode, could you tell me where that issue is coming from. Also, in the detailViewController once I receive the datasource, how do I access the strings?

Comment: @AkhilYeleswarapu I expanded on my answer

Comment: in DetailViewController.m, could you show how to extract the strings from selectednode

Comment: @AkhilYeleswarapu I updated it, you might need to tweak this a little bit

Answer (score 0):

While your current code is quite unclear about what it intends to achieve, it seems you are trying to extract some label string, and pass it to the other view controller.

Here is high level overview of the steps involved:

1 - You must first get reference to the cell you tapped. Typically, a call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should help here.

```
MyTableViewCell * cell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

2 - Get the label reference from cell:

```
UILabel * label = [cell viewWithTag:TAG_ASSIGNED];  //TAG_ASSIGNED should be assigned under cellForRowAtIndexPath earlier.
```

Note that there are other ways to get label from cell if you have custom class for your cell - and have assigned outlets for UILabel - this is very common design but out of scope for the answer here.

3 - Get the text of the label:

```
NSString * text = label.text;
```

4 - Instantiate View Controller - do this only once and not upon each tap. To maintain a reference, have an iVar assigned to it.

Like in .h file:

```
NoViewController * noViewController;
```

In .m file, under `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (!noViewController)
{
   noViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NoViewController"];
}
```

All in all, your didSelectRowForIndexPath should look like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       MyTableViewCell * cell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       UILabel * label = [cell viewWithTag:TAG_ASSIGNED];  //TAG_ASSIGNED should be assigned under cellForRowAtIndexPath    earlier.    
       NSString * text = label.text;
       if (!noViewController)
       {
          noViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NoViewController"];
       }    //Do whatever now..    
}
```

And that should do it, provided that is what you want!

Comment: Edited question title (something that should have been done in the beginning) to reflect "what should be done" - hopefully, newcomers will realize reasoning behind downvotes.